# FLTK version 1.3.2, Visual studio 2012 and the first example of Stroustrup's PPP book

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, visual-studio-2012, fltk

PLEASE, just look at each step that I want to do and if any step is wrong just tell me to revise it.

**1-** Now I have the MS VS 2012 compiler on my C:\ drive, (*C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0*).

**2-** I went to **fltk** website and downloaded the **version 1.3.2** because I thought it’s new so it can support better. (*http://www.fltk.org/software.php?VERSION=1.3.2&FILE=fltk/1.3.2/fltk-1.3.2-source.tar.gz*)

**3-** After unzipping that package on my desktop, I went to this path (*C:\Users\CS\Desktop\fltk-1.3.2-source\fltk-1.3.2\ide\VisualC6*) and found the “fltk.dsw” file there. I double clicked on it and pressed OK button. Every “.dsp” file was chosen in advance.

**4-** Then a message appeared saying, “Migrating solution projects and items”. And there were 84 items and after that some related operations occurred.

**5-** From the **Build** menu I chose **Build Solution** and clicked on it. It took some time to be finished and at the end, this message appeared:

```
           *82>  fltk_gldll.vcxproj -> C:\Users\CS\Desktop\fltk-1.3.2-source\fltk-          1.3.2\ide\VisualC6\.\Debug/fltk_gldll\fltk_gldll.dll
                  ========== Build: 84 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped* ==========
```

**6-** Then I closed the Visual Studio and from the main folder of **FLTK** I opened the **lib** folder and copied seven lib files except **README.lib** file into this path of my machine (*C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\lib*).

**7-** Then I went to main folder of **FLTK** and copied the **FL** folder into this path (*C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\include*). Now that *include* directory contains a folder named FL.

**8-** And also I found **fltk.sln** file in this path (*C:\Users\CS\Downloads\Compressed\fltk-1.3.2-source\fltk-1.3.2\ide\VisualC2010*). I installed it too (then **Build Solution**). Shouldn’t would I install it also?

**9-** I then created a “Win32 Project” from Visual Studio named it to “Win32Project1”. And did the works as follows:

Win32Project1 --> OK --> Next --> Clicking on “empty project” --> Finish.
In “Solution Explorer” right click on “Win32Project1” --> choosing “Add” --> new item --> choosing “C++ file (.cpp)” --> naming the project to “Win32Project1” --> Add.

**10-** Now this new project is empty and in bottom there is only this message:  *VMware Virtual Debugger loaded successfully*. That’s why because I installed VMware Workstation program on my machine I think.

**11-** Then I clicked on **Project** menu and chose **Properties**.

**12-** Then **Linker** --> **Input** and in the **Additional Dependencies** text field, I wrote this text:  *fltkd.lib wsock32.lib comctl32.lib fltkjpegd.lib fltkimagesd.lib*

**13-** In the **Ignore Specific default Libraries**  text field, I wrote **libcd.lib**.

**14-** Then **C/C++** --> **Code Generation**, and in the **Runtime Library** the **Multi-threaded Debug DLL (/MDd)** is chosen in advance. So I simply clicked on OK only.

**15-** Then I wrote the simple code of page 1160 (*D.5*) as follows on that project and pressed **F5**.

```
#include <FL/Fl.h>
#include <FL/Fl_box.h>
#include <FL/Fl_Window.h>

//***************************

int main() 
{
  Fl_Window window(200, 200, "Window title");
  Fl_Box box(0,0,200,200, "Hey, I mean, He llo, World! ");
  window.show();
  return Fl::run();
}
```

**16-** An error occurred saying:

E*rror 1 error LNK1104: cannot open file 'fltkd.lib wsock32.lib comctl32.lib fltkjpegd.lib fltkimagesd.lib'            c:\Users\CS\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\Win32Project1\Win32Project1\LINK*

So I returned to the **Linker** --> **Input** and in the **Additional Dependencies** text field, I clicked on <*Edit…*>, and separated each *.lib* file by a new line. And again ran.
Next error was this:
                       *Error 1 error LNK1104: cannot open file 'fltkjpegd.lib'    c:\Users\CS\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\Win32Project1\Win32Project1\LINK*

**17-** So I again went to the (*fltk-1.3.2-source\fltk-1.3.2\lib*) and copied all the *.lib* files except for readme, (there were 13 *.lib* files) and pasted them into that path (*C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\lib*) and reran the code. This time code succeeded. WOW.

**18-** So after this success I downloaded the Programming-code zip file from Stroustrup's website and copied all the **.h** and **.cpp** files (10 files) from the **GUI** folder into my include folder of this path (*C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\include*). There was also a *Makefile* file which I didn’t copy it into the include directory. And then I cleared the previous code and wrote the code written in page 441 (A first example) as follows into that project and ran it.

```
//
// This is example code from Chapter 12.3 "A first example" of
// "Programming -- Principles and Practice Using C++" by Bjarne Stroustrup
//

#include "Simple_window.h"    // get access to our window library
#include "Graph.h"            // get access to our graphics library facilities

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

int main()
{
    using namespace Graph_lib;   // our graphics facilities are in Graph_lib

    Point tl(100,100);           // to become top left  corner of window

    Simple_window win(tl,600,400,"Canvas");    // make a simple window

    Polygon poly;                // make a shape (a polygon)

    poly.add(Point(300,200));    // add a point
    poly.add(Point(350,100));    // add another point
    poly.add(Point(400,200));    // add a third point 

    poly.set_color(Color::red);  // adjust properties of poly

    win.attach (poly);           // connect poly to the window

    win.wait_for_button();       // give control to the display engine
}

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

**19-** There were 13 errors which first error was saying:

*Error    8 error C2872: 'Polygon' : ambiguous symbol              C:\users\cs\documents\visual studio 2012\projects\win32project1\win32project1\win32project1.cpp      20*

**20-** So I used this snip code **Graph_lib::Polygon poly;** instead of this **Polygon poly;** and ran the code again. Again there were 11 errors, first is this:

*Error    9          error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "protected: virtual void __thiscall Graph_lib::Window::draw(void)" (?draw@Window@Graph_lib@@MAEXXZ)            C:\Users\CS\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\Win32Project1\Win32Project1\Win32Project1.obj*

**Now what any more effort I can to do?**

Comment: Pretty exhausting just to read.  You keep going, you are making all the beginner mistakes that you need to make.  Makes C++ programmers feel pretty special afterwards, conqueror of the machine and all that.

Comment: You need to add the graph_lib library to the linker input.  Add it on a separate line before fltkd.lib.

Comment: I inputted graph_lib.lib before fltkd.lib separated by new line. They are: _graph_lib.lib fltkd.lib wsock32.lib comctl32.lib fltkjpegd.lib fltkimagesd.lib_. Now there is a new error which is _Error 1 error LNK1104: cannot open file 'graph_lib.lib' C:\Users\CS\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\Win32Project1\Win32Project1\LINK_.

Comment: Isn't there an answer!?

Answer (score 2):

I finally found and solved the problem. This is as follows:

First, there is no need to add some library named *Graph_lib* into the **Linker Input** text field even if we assume there is a library with that name in the whole of the machine! 
The only needed change to be done to the project of code of page 411 (A first example) of PPP is to add the **Graph_lib::** before the **Polygon poly;**. After that what we need is to adding some *.cpp* files to the project. I added all the *.cpp* files of **GUI** folder that I had downloaded them from Stroustrup's website to the project (they are **Graph.cpp**, **GUI.cpp**, **Simple_window.cpp** and **window.cpp**) and reran the project. It **successfully** showed the result.
In any way, I'm thankful of you nice guys, especially, "cup".