# Why using namespace doesn't work in my C++ project?

Tags: c++, namespaces

I after vast effort could (details are in here [FLTK version 1.3.2, Visual studio 2012 and the first example of Stroustrup's PPP book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21063872/fltk-version-1-3-2-visual-studio-2012-and-the-first-example-of-stroustrups-ppp)) to ran the below code;

```
#include <Simple_window.h>    
#include <Graph.h>  

//*********************************************

int main()
{
    using namespace Graph_lib; 

    Point tl(100,100);
    Simple_window win(tl,600,400,"Canvas");


    Graph_lib::Polygon poly;
    poly.add(Point(300,200));
    poly.add(Point(350,100));
    poly.add(Point(400,200));
    win.attach(poly);


    win.set_label("Canvas");
    win.wait_for_button();   
}
```

But for `Polygon poly;` I should use `Graph_lib::`, while since I have added the statement `using namespace Graph_lib;` at the top of the code's body (just below the `main` function) so there should not be any need to use the `Graph_lib::` for *Polygon*. But in effect without using it I get *ambiguous symbol* error. and also even I remove that statement (`using namespace Graph_lib;`) I don't get any error. My question is that why that statement doesn't work for that code and I have to use `Graph_lib::`?

Comment: There's probably another `Polygon` symbol in the global namespace already?

Comment: what do you mean by global namespace?

Answer (score 5):

Most likely you have something else called `Polygon`. Namespaces exist so that you can avoid this type of problem.

Here's a simplified example:

```
namespace Foo
{
  struct Bar {};
}

void Bar() {}

int main()
{
  using namespace Foo; // I really really know what I am doing, seriously!
  Bar b;               // Oh dear.
}
```

In the output:

> error: reference to 'Bar' is ambiguous

This is one good example of the pitfalls of the `using namespace X` anti-idiom. This really should be avoided, or at the very least limited to the smallest of scopes.

Comment: If you would be so kind to mention explicitly that "so this is why should not be (ab)using namespace directives"...

Comment: @H2CO3 Done (avoiding my usual "never say `using namespace X`" rant which invariably leads to a stream of comments).

Comment: Thanks! (Of course it leads to a comment fight -- not everyone can be right nor experienced. If someone isn't, he will find it a personal offense if you tell him never to `use namespace X`... :/ )

Comment: So, _using namespace X;_ and then _Polygon poly;_ with _X::Polygon poly;_ do not equal to each other, yes?

Comment: @abbasi Right. If there is something else called `Polygon` in the same scope the first version results in ambiguity, the second one doesn't.

Comment: Excuse me if I extend the discussion but my intention is to completely understand the issue. You said _in the same scope_, what scope (in this code) are you referring to? The scope of the _main_ function? Or the scope of the _Graph_lib_?

Comment: @abbasi in this particular case, the scope is the `main` function. That is where `Bar b` is declared. But it could apply to some other function, the global namespace, a class, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Likely, there is another Polygon declared either in global namespace, or in some namespace you're already "using" (like if you have `using namespace XXX;` in another included header, which is not a good practice, and something like `XXX::Polygon` is declared).

What I can suggest you as a quick solution (if you really want to use Graph_lib's Polygon without "Graph_lib::", is

```
using Graph_lib::Polygon;
```

instead of (or next to)

```
using namespace Graph_lib;
```