# C++ fill color in shapes using FLTK doesn't work for circles

Tags: c++, fltk

I installed FLTK 1.3.X from fltk.org on my visual studio 2012 compiler and use PPP book for C++ programming ([this](http://www.stroustrup.com/Programming/PPP1.html)).
My problem is about filling a Shape in. For example please observe this code:

```
#include <Simple_window.h>

using namespace Graph_lib;
int main()
{
    Simple_window win(Point(100,100), 1000, 600, "Binary_tree");
    Graph_lib::Circle c(Point(200,200),50);
    c.set_color(Color::red);
    c.set_fill_color(Color::blue);
    Graph_lib::Ellipse e(Point(100,100),50,30);
    e.set_color(Color::blue);
    e.set_fill_color(Color::red);
    Graph_lib::Rectangle r(Point(250,200),Point(350,300));
    r.set_color(Color::green);
    r.set_fill_color(Color::red);
    win.attach(r);
    win.attach(e);
    win.attach(c);
    win.wait_for_button();
}
```

When I run the program, All three `Shapes` are drawn on window but only the `Rectangle` is filled in!
Why?
`set_color` works for the three and apparently the `set_fill_color` is defined for all `Shapes` and it too should work but why it doesn't for `Circle` and `Ellipse`?

[This](http://www.stroustrup.com/Programming/Graphics/) is the `.CPP` and `.h` files ( )

Comment: There isn't any idea!?

Comment: This isn't anything to do with fltk: it is to do with graph_lib which is written on top of fltk.  Where did you get graph_lib from and which platform are you running on?

Comment: My machine is Windows 7 and compiler is M Visual Studio 2012. I installed _FLTK_ version 1.3.2 and _Graph_lib_ has come from it I think.

Comment: Took a while to find graph_lib - it comes from Stourstrup's site.  Anyway, ran your program and it fills the circle and ellipse.  It goes into fl_arci.cxx routine Fl_Graphics_Driver::pie which should fill up the circle.

Comment: What version of FLTK you used please? The 1.3.2?

Comment: Yes - 1.3.2.  It is possible that your FLTK has not been built correctly.  Did you build it from source or did you get it as a prebuilt library?  If you didn't build it from source, get the source from the fltk site, go to the IDE directory, convert the VS10 solution to VS11 and rebuild.

Comment: Excuse me, I'm not familiar with those phrases but to inform you how I installed FLTK please read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21063872/fltk-version-1-3-2-visual-studio-2012-and-the-first-example-of-stroustrups-ppp). I appreciate your further guidance.

Comment: On step 3, instead of going into VC6 and using the dsw, you should be going into VC2010 and converting that solution.  It is more compatible with VS11.

Comment: OK, I do that on step 3 and go on the rest of steps as before. But what I should do is reinstalling FLTK on the existing one or I should uninstall (?) this version someway and install it again by that new way?

Comment: Instead of installing/reinstalling you could do this - set an environment variable FLTK to the 1.3.2 diectory.  Then in the include add $(FLTK) and libs add $(FLTK)/lib.

Answer (score 0):

Probably, it was you who started the thread regarding this issue on another website where I found a solution, but in order to help others, who also struggles with this problem, I will make this post. [Here](http://www.stroustrup.com/Programming/Graphics/) you can download the working Stroustrup's library. If you don't want to rewrite all the files, just change the code in the function "Circle::draw_lines()" in Graph.cpp to this one and recompile the library:

```
if (fill_color().visibility()) {    // fill
    fl_color(fill_color().as_int());
    fl_pie(point(0).x,point(0).y,r+r-1,r+r-1,0,360);
    fl_color(color().as_int()); // reset color
}

if (color().visibility()) {
    fl_color(color().as_int());
    fl_arc(point(0).x,point(0).y,r+r,r+r,0,360);
}
```